# How to save boolean values in isolated storage and retrieve it in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

How to save boolean values in isolated storage and retrieve it in XNA.

Say I have four boolean values

bool colour1=true;

bool colour2=false;

bool colour3=true;

bool colour4=false;

and I want to save it after exiting the game

and again when I am opening the game I want to read these values.

Please help me.Previously I was using isolatedstoragesettings,but as it is not working in windows phone 8,I cant use it any more...

Answer (score 0):

Use binary, txt or xml file.
XML good for complex data, and txt will be better for list of key-value pairs like in your case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx